# Angular 4 Data Undefined outside of Subscribe

Tags: angular, subscribe

I know that a few topics exist with this question, but I tried a lot of them and nothing seems to work...

I have this method:

```
listAllUsersOfProgram() {
        this.programDetailsService.findAllUsersById(this.programId).subscribe(
          res => {
              this.users = res
              this.userSearch = res
              console.log(this.users)
          },
          err => console.log(`aconteceu algum erro: ${err}`)
      )
    }
```

the `console.log(this.users)` works fine..
but, when I try to use the data from this.users in an table, using

```
<tr ngFor="let user of userSearch |
                                paginate:{itemsPerPage:20, currentPage:p}">
                                <td>{{ user.name }}</td>

                            </tr>
```

it gives me that this is `Undefined`

the method `listAllUsersOfProgram()` is called on the `ngOnInit method(onInit interface)`

How to solve this?

Edit:
Complete error message

```
ProgramDetailsComponent.html:93 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ProgramDetailsComponent.html:93)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.es5.js:13105)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12256)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12599)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.es5.js:12557)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12252)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12599)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.es5.js:12557)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12252)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12599)
View_ProgramDetailsComponent_4  @   ProgramDetailsComponent.html:93
DebugContext_.logError  @   core.es5.js:13407
ErrorHandler.handleError    @   core.es5.js:1080
(anonymous) @   core.es5.js:4819
ZoneDelegate.invoke @   zone.js:392
Zone.run    @   zone.js:142
NgZone.runOutsideAngular    @   core.es5.js:3844
ApplicationRef_.tick    @   core.es5.js:4819
(anonymous) @   core.es5.js:4684
ZoneDelegate.invoke @   zone.js:392
onInvoke    @   core.es5.js:3890
ZoneDelegate.invoke @   zone.js:391
Zone.run    @   zone.js:142
NgZone.run  @   core.es5.js:3821
next    @   core.es5.js:4684
schedulerFn @   core.es5.js:3635
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @   Subscriber.js:239
SafeSubscriber.next @   Subscriber.js:186
Subscriber._next    @   Subscriber.js:127
Subscriber.next @   Subscriber.js:91
Subject.next    @   Subject.js:56
EventEmitter.emit   @   core.es5.js:3621
checkStable @   core.es5.js:3855
onLeave @   core.es5.js:3934
onInvokeTask    @   core.es5.js:3884
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @   zone.js:424
Zone.runTask    @   zone.js:192
ZoneTask.invokeTask @   zone.js:499
invokeTask  @   zone.js:1540
globalZoneAwareCallback @   zone.js:1566
ProgramDetailsComponent.html:93 ERROR CONTEXT 
DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 18, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
View_ProgramDetailsComponent_4  @   ProgramDetailsComponent.html:93
DebugContext_.logError  @   core.es5.js:13407
ErrorHandler.handleError    @   core.es5.js:1085
(anonymous) @   core.es5.js:4819
ZoneDelegate.invoke @   zone.js:392
Zone.run    @   zone.js:142
NgZone.runOutsideAngular    @   core.es5.js:3844
ApplicationRef_.tick    @   core.es5.js:4819
(anonymous) @   core.es5.js:4684
ZoneDelegate.invoke @   zone.js:392
onInvoke    @   core.es5.js:3890
ZoneDelegate.invoke @   zone.js:391
Zone.run    @   zone.js:142
NgZone.run  @   core.es5.js:3821
next    @   core.es5.js:4684
schedulerFn @   core.es5.js:3635
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @   Subscriber.js:239
SafeSubscriber.next @   Subscriber.js:186
Subscriber._next    @   Subscriber.js:127
Subscriber.next @   Subscriber.js:91
Subject.next    @   Subject.js:56
EventEmitter.emit   @   core.es5.js:3621
checkStable @   core.es5.js:3855
onLeave @   core.es5.js:3934
onInvokeTask    @   core.es5.js:3884
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @   zone.js:424
Zone.runTask    @   zone.js:192
ZoneTask.invokeTask @   zone.js:499
invokeTask  @   zone.js:1540
globalZoneAwareCallback @   zone.js:1566
```

solved..it was missing the `*` in the `ngFor` ..

Comment: What is the exact, and complete error message? What does paginate do and how? You realize that userSearch is undefiend until the response to the asynchronous http service call comes back, right? And that happens long after the component has been displayed.

Comment: update the question with the error, paginate is for pagination if the number of results are large, but not the problem(works fine in other htmls of the project)

Comment: So that must be a big bug of the paginate pipe, which seems to return a non-empty array even though the input to paginate is undefined: the template tried displaying the name of a user, although it's undefined. Or your actual array of users contains undefined values.

Comment: found the bug..it was missing the "*" before the "ngFor" --'... working fine now..thanks for the help do

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `async` pipe or maybe add an `*ngIf="userSearch"` in a parent `<div>`

Comment: cant put ngIf and ngFor on the same element

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that userSearch is undefined until you set it.  Which happens after the view initializes.  Your options are to guard agaisnt this with ngIf or intiialize it to an empty list.

```
userSearch = [];
```

or

```
<ng-container *ngIf="userSearch">...content...</ng-container>
```

or the async pipe, but that has other implications for your code.